# How to make a javascript slideshow using for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a javascript slideshow using a for loop
Javascript code

```
        var Image_slide = new Array("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg");// image container
    var Img_Lenght = Image_slide.length; // container length - 1

    function slide(){
        for (var i = 0; i < Img_Lenght; i++) {

        Image_slide[i];

        };
        document.slideshow.src = Image_slide[i];
    }
    function auto(){
        setInterval("slide()", 1000);
    }

    window.onload = auto;
```

html code

```
<img src="img1.jpg" name="slideshow">
```

i can't figure out what is the problem of this code it just run img3 continuously without looping img1 and it also skip img2 from the loop

Comment: Ok.. You code as it is now does this: When the document is loaded it calls a function that will call another function every second. In that function, you count from 0 to the length of Image_slide. When the counting is finished, you assign an image. Variable i will always have the value 3 since you are doing this after the for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better option to solve this than to use a for loop is to simply skip the for loop all-together. Using a for loop is really too complicated and there's a far simpler solution.

Rather than using a for loop, simply assign the slides directly and keep track of positioning:

```
var Image_slide = new Array("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg");// image container
var Img_Length  = Image_slide.length; // container length - 1
var Img_current = 0

function slide() {
    if(Img_current >= Img_Length) {
        Img_current = 0;
    }
    document.slideshow.src = Image_slide[Img_current];
    Img_current++;
}
function auto(){
    setInterval(slide, 1000);
}
window.onload = auto;
```

Interval should already run anyway. The loop inside the auto is redundant and simply messes it up. You only need to get one array element each time, not the whole loop. Looping through it every time will only return the last result.

You need to keep track of your position and reset the position to 0 once you reach the max length.

I'd also recommend at least 3 seconds for the interval instead of 1 second. One second I think is a bit too fast.

Here's an example of the correct solution on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUX9P/

NOW, that said, the question is actually asking how to make it work with a for loop. I've written up a potential solution to the problem (untested so I can't guarantee it will work), but I HIGHLY ADVISE NOT TO DO IT THIS WAY. It shouldn't be TOO bad overall, its just far more complicated and the solution above is so simple, this solution really isn't worth it.

```
var Image_slide = new Array("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg");// image container
var Img_Length = Image_slide.length; // container length - 1

function slide(){
    delay = 0;
    start = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < Img_Length; i++) {
        if(start && delay < 1000) {
            delay += 1;
            i--;
        }
        else {
            document.slideshow.src = Image_slide[i];
            delay = 0;
        }
        start = true;
    }
}
function auto(){
    setInterval("slide()", 1000);
}

window.onload = auto;
```

I cannot guarantee this will work, but essentially, the code I updated in slide() initializes a delay variable and a start variable. When the loop is run through once, it automatically activates start and always sets the first value in source.

Once start has been set, every consecutive time it will increment the delay variable until delay hits 1000, and it will decrement the i variable so that the for loop doesn't increment i over the cap (the length of the array). Basically, it sets i back by one so that the increment in for puts it back to where it should be, preventing it from moving on to the next variable until it finally processes the current entry.

This should, in theory, work. You may need to increase the delay significantly though; that 1000 should not actually equal one second; it'll likely go far faster than that. But I may be mistaken; it might run in one second, I haven't had a chance to try it out yet.

Clearly, the complexity of this is quite high, its just not worth it. My first option should be used instead.

Comment: Heh. Arrived at almost the same example, so just adding my jsFiddle link. Feel free to edit or remove it.

Comment: jsFiddle example is fine. I should start using it myself, really.

Comment: @Tieson T
i know your code before and i know it will work but i want to access the array(images) via for loop

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. What are you trying to do? The for loop won't work because you're just looping right to the end again, so its only ever going to display the last result. Yeah, there's potentially a way to make it work with a for loop, but what's the point? You can do the exact same thing without one.

Comment: it is just for curiosity
i tried to improve it but it never work

`  var Image_slide = new Array();// image container
  Image_slide[0] = "img1.jpg";
  Image_slide[1] = "img2.jpg";
  Image_slide[2] = "img3.jpg";

  function slide(){
   for (var i = 0; i < Image_slide.length; i++) {
    if (i > Image_slide.length) {
     i = 0;
    };
    document.slideshow.src = (Image_slide[i]);
   };

  }
  function auto(){
   setInterval("slide()", 2000);
  }

  window.onload = auto;`

Comment: I updated my answer. Check out the second solution I posted. I don't know why you really want the answer to this, but that *should* work, as long as you tweak the delay value. Due to how complex it is, though, it really isn't worth it. There's a far easier and more efficient solution.